# How can I back up a sharepoint site?

Tags: backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I schedule site collection or site backups?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8592/how-do-i-schedule-site-collection-or-site-backups)

I would like to backup a SharePoint 2010 site every Friday, How could I able to schedule it to run automatically on each Wednesday and to save to a particular folder in the server ...